# Hide Report Types from Users?

Tags: security, reporting

I know that Report Types are hidden from Users who don't have access to the underlying objects.  Is there a way to block Users from building new reports with standard Report Types?

**Use Case:** We have data in Salesforce that folks are welcome to access in the interface, but we don't want them to be able to easily export that data to excel or csv.  My thought it to make Custom Report Types exposing only the fields I want them to be able to manipulate freely, but I don't know how to block their access to the standard Report Types, if that's even possible.

**Clarification:** This isn't just about export, and you can ignore that example if you want.  I have a group of employees whom I'd like to empower to create reports while simplifying their experience by only presenting the report types they will need to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more research and it seems this is **not currently possible**.

I found [this idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br1s) on the IdeaExchange, which includes the following comment from Product Management:

> ...Today, however: 1) you can't restrict a user to one report type when creating a report, and forbid them from using another...

As of 9/2/2013, the comment is dated "more than a year ago," but I couldn't find anything in the Salesforce documentation to indicate that this behavior has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Is this about limiting the ability of people to create the report in the first place, or about being about to export the details of an existing report?

If it's about creating reports, generally I'll only have a trusted few people that can create actual reports, and these people are taught what they can or can't do.

End users should only be running existing reports.

In regards to permissions on report types, I'm not aware of any fine grained control available to you, beyond whether a profile can create reports.

Comment: I agree with the guideline that "End users should only be running existing reports," but I don't think that's a hard and fast rule.  In this case, I have some senior-level employees with good tech skills, and I'd like to empower them to create some reports while simplifying their experience.  I could make all the canned reports for them to customize, but I'd like to go one level up from that.

Comment: I think it then needs to be handled with training.
The description would be critical in assisting them to choose the correct record type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several ways for this:

1. You can create a report folder, and give access to that report only to the users you want.
   [image]

[image]

2. If you only refer to export - than in your setup, you can block the export option according to profiles.
   [image]
   this option may limit you, since it's per profile, but it's an option (and you can overcome it, if you deny access to all, and using permission sets, grant export to others.

Comment: this addresses visibility and permissions on the reports themselves, but not on the custom report types.  I would like users to be able to create reports, but limit what report types are available for their use.

Answer (score 0):

The admin can of course restrict what fields are available in the custom report types so users can access an object via the correct UI but only see some fields in reports if the concern is they are able to produce 
& export a report on the whole object.

Comment: True - but nothing stops the user from recreating a similar report (with access to any fields) but using a different report type, such as the standard report types.  Hence the question about totally hiding report types from certain profiles.